# Forget iPlayer and video feeds, is there a way to view BBC.co.uk outside of the UK so I can read domestic articles?

Tags: url, browsing, localization

I'm having a tough time finding an answer to my problem because after every search I run, I either can't find anything useful or all recommendations assume that I'm outside the UK and wanting to stream BBC content.  I'm not interested in the BBC iPlayer.

What I'd like to do is actually browse the articles from within the BBC, specifically, UK domestic news articles.  The problem is that when you enter "bbc.co.uk" into your address bar, the site loads for about half a second, you see that there are various news articles present, and then you are redirected to "bbc.com", which seems to be the outward-facing site of the BBC and is different than the bbc.co.uk domestic front page.

I imagine that most of these articles on the UK front page are on BBC.com, however, I'm more interested in the local domestic news of the UK and I'd like to see what's being presented to the British public on their internet front page versus what's being curated for the rest of the world.

Without having to do the full proxy/VPN route that people use to get iPlayer working, is a there a simple way to browse to see and browse the bbc.co.uk front page from outside the UK?  Again, I'm not interested in streaming video.  I just want to follow and read the news.

Comment: Do you have access to a pc that is inside the UK? If so you could use remote control software to control that pc and visit the web from that pc.

Comment: Nope. Many search engines and websites use your IP address to determine what they display. BBC is one of those websites. If you want actual UK information, you have to "trick" the search engines/websites into thinking you're actually within the UK or a region it accepts for displaying "local" information. The proxy/VPN route does exactly that. It connects you to a server providing you with a correct "local" IP address, thereby allowing you to see "local" content.

Comment: Might not be a direct help, but the iPhone BBC News app works just fine when I'm out of the country. It was bought [free] on a UK account & installed & set up there.

Answer (score 1):

> Without having to do the full proxy/VPN route that people use to get iPlayer working, is a there a simple way to browse to see and browse the bbc.co.uk front page from outside the UK?

No, there isn't.

The problem is the same actually but whilst the videos (iPlayer) are effectively blocked the news aren't but you're always redirected to the "international" website.

So, the only way to make it work like at home is to trick it into thinking you're "at home" and that implies the use of the exact same workaround you're already familiar with for iPlayer.

Comment: Thank you.  I'm sure this is the right answer, but I'm going to leave this open a bit, just in case someone has found a work around.  They only reason I remain optimistic is, because as I stated, the page does load but you are then redirected after half a second.  I'm curious is there is an easy way to block the redirection and, possibly, any errors that it may cause.

Comment: If it was possible to "block the redirection" we all would be enjoying iPlayer abroad without proxy/VPN ;)

Comment: They don't preserve the content by redirecting your requests, per se.  Instead, they have IP address blocks.  This is why the VPNs within the UK work.  They IPs are assigned from ISPs who are based in the UK. But, content isn't being blocked if you see it.  There is, rather, some form of  localization detection and then forcing the jump after data has already been sent from the UK content servers.

Answer (score 1):

Yes there is. Just spin up a VM in either Azure or AWS, select 'UK West' as the region in Azure or 'eu-west-2' (London) in EC2, and browse to bbc.co.uk. It'll cost you a whopping $0.116 an hour on Azure. Then, when you're done browsing, spin the VM back down, and just use it the next day. That comes out to $42.34 in Azure expenses annually.